# Javascript. Code works without specifying its this value

Tags: javascript, function

```js
if (!Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce) {
  Array.prototype.mapUsingReduce = function(callback, thisArg) {
    return this.reduce(function(mappedArray, currentValue, index, array) {
      mappedArray[index] = callback.call(thisArg, currentValue, index, array)
      return mappedArray
    }, [])
  }
}

const output=[1, 2, , 3].mapUsingReduce(
  (currentValue, index, array) => currentValue + index + array.length); // [5, 7, , 10]

console.log(output);
```

Here

```js
const output=[1, 2, , 3].mapUsingReduce(
  (currentValue, index, array) => currentValue + index + array.length);
```

Second argument `thisArg` is not passed.

And

```js
mappedArray[index] = callback.call(thisArg, currentValue, index, array)
```

Here in call function we need `thisArg`. So how does the call still work without `thisArg` specified?

I realize that arrow functions don't have `this`.

Comment: The function never uses `this`, therefore `thisArg` is irrelevant.

Comment: it still works if i change to `mappedArray[index] = callback.call(null, currentValue, index, array)`

Comment: @logan When you do that you're setting the the `callback`'s `this` to be `null`. If you used a normal function expression (not an arrow function) then your `this` inside that function will be `null` (if in strict mode)

Comment: @logan but there is no `this` used anywhere. It's irrelevant what its value is. If you have `() => 1 + 1` or `function() { return 1 + 1; }` would the result change in any way if `this` is altered?